# How to loop jQuery animate() in .each() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to have several balls make a random displacement in a given div. The code to create and style the balls is almost entirely in jQuery and it works, the problem is trying to make .animate() loop all the time, having the balls moving around in a random direction/speed in each iteration.

The first move works, but not the rest. Here is the link:  https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/19871/

```
  // Some random colors
  var colors = ["#3CC157", "#2AA7FF", "#1B1B1B", "#FCBC0F", "#F85F36"];
  var numBalls = 50;
  var balls = [];

  function makeNewPosition(){
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $('.front-bg').height();
    var w = $('.front-bg').width();
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    return [nh,nw];    
  }

  for (i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) { 
   $('.front-bg').append('<div class="ball"></div>');
   $('.ball').each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
    $(this).css('left', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '%');
    $(this).css('top', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '%');
    $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + Math.random() + ')');
    var WH = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 4;
    $(this).css({
      width:  WH + 'px',
      height: WH + 'px'
    });
  });
 }

  $('.ball').each(function() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $(this).animate({
    top: newq[0], 
    left: newq[1],
    easing: 'easeInOutQuint',
    complete: function() {
      $(this).animate({
      top: newq[0], 
      left: newq[1],
      easing: 'easeInOutQuint',
      }, Math.random() * 10000)
    }
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer lies in the statement:

> The first move works, but not the rest

You just need to put the moving logic to be repeated in repeating function at certain interval, like `setInterval()`, or `setTimeout()`

```js
  // Some random colors
  var colors = ["#3CC157", "#2AA7FF", "#1B1B1B", "#FCBC0F", "#F85F36"];
  var numBalls = 50;
  var balls = [];

  function makeNewPosition(){
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $('.front-bg').height();
    var w = $('.front-bg').width();
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    return [nh,nw];    
  }

  for (i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) { 
   $('.front-bg').append('<div class="ball"></div>');
   $('.ball').each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
    $(this).css('left', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '%');
    $(this).css('top', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '%');
    $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + Math.random() + ')');
    var WH = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 4;
    $(this).css({
      width:  WH + 'px',
      height: WH + 'px'
    });
  });
 }

var first = true;
setInterval(function() {
  $('.ball').each(function() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $(this).animate({
    top: newq[0], 
    left: newq[1],
    easing: 'easeInOutQuint',
    complete: function() {
      $(this).animate({
      top: newq[0], 
      left: newq[1],
      easing: 'easeInOutQuint',
      }, Math.random() * 10000)
    }
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
  });
}, (first?0 : 3000));
first = false;
```

```css
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.front-bg {
  min-height: 400px;
}
#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="front-bg"></div>
```